# How to make a new list from list of values of occurrences and value?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 lists one containing float values and second has number of occurrences of values from first list. How can I create a new list, that have value times occurrences?

```
values = [10.5,20.2, 50.0]
occ = [3,5,1]
```

Result should be [10.5,10.5,10.5,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,50.0]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Take a look at `zip` and use list comprehension with two for loops? `[v for v, c in zip(values, occ) for _ in range(c)]`

Comment: I have tried using double for loops but because I'm looping in the list, I am getting the values 3 times (length of occ)

Comment: @DD You can post what you've tried to the question itself. You can [edit] the question from here.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Nope, the above-mentioned list comp creates a list of number.

Comment: We can not help you with **your** code if you do not post it:  [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` with a nested `list` comprehension:

```py
values = [10.5,20.2, 50.0]
occ = [3,5,1]

result = [x for x, y in zip(values, occ) for _ in range(y)]
```

Alternatively, without using `range`:

```
result = [elem for x, y in zip(values, occ) for elem in [x] * y]
```

Output:

```
[10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 50.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to iterate both the lists in parallel, then just repeat the items number of times and add it to the resulting list, something like this:

```py
result = []
for v,m in zip(values,occ):
    result.extend([v for _ in range(m)])
                  
result
[10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 50.0]
```

Or the list-comprehension as suggested in comment:

```py
[v for v, c in zip(values, occ) for _ in range(c)]
[10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 50.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```py
sum(([v]*m for v, m in zip(values, occ)), [])
```

Not recommended for large lists. Actually not really recommended at all.

Answer (score 1):

The *pythonic* way would be using `zip` in a list comprehension as demonstrated multiple times.

You can simple loops and `enumerate()` to a similar effect - but it results in more lines of code:

```
values = [10.5,20.2, 50.0]
occ = [3, 5, 1]

result = []

# enumerate returns a tuple: position, value 
# of all values of the iterable you give it
for index, times in enumerate(occ):
    # use the index to get the value from the other list you 
    # have and append it multiple times
    for _ in range(times):
        result.append(values[index])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 50.0]
```

See [enumerate() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 0):

```
output =[]
for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(occ[i]):
        output.append(values[i])
print(output)

[10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 50.0]
```